# Using an if statement with Rails ActiveRecord find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, exception

I want to check that a user is included in a group.  In an attempt to do this, I have the following statement:

```
user_id = current_user.id
unless (group.user.find(user_id))
  redirect_to different_path
end
```

Looking at the docs, "A failure to find the requested object raises a ResourceNotFound
exception if the find was called with an id."  How do I write the unless statement so that it operates properly?

Comment: Define "properly". Can't you rescue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defined a relation between group and users, you can call `current_user.group.present?` This will return false if there is no related object.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the redirect as part of Exception handling

```
redirect_to path if group.user.find(user_id)

rescue ResourceNotFound
  redirect_to differenct_path
end
```

alternatively and probably a better way would be to build your logic around

```
user.groups.include?(group)
```